# Group rows without "GROUP BY" expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this table and I would like to do the following :

```
idstep   idproject   beg_date  end_date
   1        1
   2        1
   3        1
   4        1
   1        2
   2        2
   3        2
   4        2
   5        2
   1        3
   2        3
   3        3
```

**Retrieve the Maximum steps for each project without using "GROUP BY"**

*Using the GROUP BY clause, I get the result that I want which is the following:*

```
  SELECT MAX(idstep), idproject 
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY idproject;
```

Result:

```
    idstep     idproject
    4            1
    5            2
    3            3
```

Please, can anyone here can help me out with this issue?

Comment: I'm curious. If using GROUP BY gives you what you want, why do you NOT want to use it?

Comment: If you already get the result you want with a nice concise query why do you want an alternative? Sounds like homework.

Comment: Group without GROUP BY? Any specific reason to make query complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this makes more sense to use GROUP BY for this particular case, but this should work:

```
SELECT t.project, t.step
FROM YourTable t
  LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 on t.step < t2.step and t.project = t2.project
where t2.step IS NULL
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05ceb/1).

You could also use NOT EXISTS (feel like I've been using it all night), although I personally prefer the LEFT JOIN / NULL approach:

```
SELECT t.project, t.step
FROM YourTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM YourTable t2 
  WHERE t.step < t2.step 
    AND t.project = t2.project
)
```

More fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebbc2/1

Good luck.